# How can I position the menu buttons in the center?

Tags: html, css

I have the following css file:

```
/*** Tabbed Navigation ***/
.ls-nav {
  display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}
.ls-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        transition: .3s background-color;
}
.ls-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #919191;
}
.ls-nav .current a {
  background: #ffaacc;
}
.currentCrossLink {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ls-nav ul {  
  padding:0;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ls-nav ul li {
  display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}
.ls-nav ul li a {
  display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}
```

and the final effect looks like this:
[image] 
I would like to have this menu items not aligned to the left, but rather centered - can you help me with that? Thanks!

about the html code, it looks like this:

```
<div class="liquid-slider" id="slider-1">
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">Slide 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">Slide 2</h2>
      <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">Slide 3</h2>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">Slide 4</h2>
      <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

as you can see there's no ul li list or anything, I think it's handled by the Javascript plugin that I'm using - http://liquidslider.com/documentation/

Comment: text-align: center on your UL element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `inline-block` to make center align navigation!

Add `text-align: center` to `ul`

```
.ls-nav ul {  
  padding:0;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Make `inline-block` to all `li`

```
.ls-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}
```

Also make the wrapper `block` as you can not have `block` `ul` inside the inline wrapper!

```
.ls-nav {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 .ls-nav ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 5em; // You can use: px's / em's or % here
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

give *.ls-nav* ul a **width** property